# convert an array of checkbox values to a list

Tags: vb.net, jquery

I'm trying to retrieve a group of checkbox values, store into an array, and then use that array in my ajax data parameter.

I am getting an error back from my page stating that the data is not in the correct format.  It needs to be an ienumerable.

Here is what I have so far:

```
    var years = new Array();
    $("#years input:checkbox[name=type]:checked").each(function() {
        if (checked == true) {
            years.push($(this).attr('name') + "=" + $(this).val());
        }
    });

    var ajaxData = years;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        dataType: "json",
        data: ajaxData
    });
```

How can I convert the array to a list-like format?

Thanks!

Comment: What is that variable `checked` doing? Also, shouldn't that statement always return true since you're only selecting "checked" checkboxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As tymeJV mentioned in the comment, you do not need to check if the checkbox is checked since you are already selecting those that are checked, so just do the following:

```
var years = new Array();
$("#years input:checkbox[name=type]:checked").each(function() {
   years.push($(this).attr('name') + '=' + $(this).val());
});
```

You should probably give your array a name:

```
var ajaxData = {
    years:years
};
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        dataType: "json",
        data: ajaxData
    });
```

Than from your server, you can grab the post variable named "years" containing the array.

Comment: What does years:years do?  I'm not quite how that statment works.  Thanks

Comment: The jquery ajax data attribute is supposed to be a PlainObject or String, not an array.  But your object can contain an array, so in this case the object contains an array called years

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var years = [];

$("#years input:checkbox[name=type]:checked").each(function () {
    years.push({
        name: $(this).attr('name'),
        val: $(this).val()
    });
});

var ajaxData = years;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use JSON:

```
    var years = {
        theYears: []
    };

       var years = new Array();
        $("#years input:checkbox[name=type]:checked").each(function() {
            if (checked == true) {
                theYears.push({
                    "name" : $(this).attr("name"), 
                    "value" : + $(this).val()});
            }
        });


   var ajaxData = theYears;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        dataType: "json",
        data: ajaxData
    });
```